# how to handle "main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" such error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, addeventlistener

Is there any Error or  any variable that is causing the null value error

```
    // Select DOM Items
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuNav = document.querySelector('.menu-nav');
const menuBranding = document.querySelector('.menu-branding');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

// Set Initial State Of Menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
    if (!showMenu) {
        menuBtn.classList.add('close');
        menu.classList.add('show');
        menuNav.classList.add('show');
        menuBranding.classList.add('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('show'));

        // Set Menu State
        showMenu = true;
    } else {
        menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
        menu.classList.remove('show');
        menuNav.classList.remove('show');
        menuBranding.classList.remove('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'));

        // Set Menu State
        showMenu = false;
    }
}
```

here menuBtn.addEventLister is showing the this error :

> main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener'
>   of null
>       at main.js:11

Please explain how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The querySelector return null, because there are no element with the class `.menu-btn` into your DOM

You can catch the error by testing the variable menuBtn before adding the event

```
menuBtn && menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
```